# Fancybox prev/next area is too wide

Tags: fancybox

look i'm using the gallery function on iframes to show PDF files, but my problem here is the area to tap prev/next is big, how i can modify this space to make it thinner.

I'm using a touch screen and i need modify this area.

Answer (score 0):

well i find it looking in css files,

int the file /fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css i find this block:

```
    fancybox-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 8040;
}
```

and modify width property reducing the %